# Where can I config XCode.app location in Unity?

Tags: xcode, macos, unity-game-engine

When building a MacOS app on Mac using Unity (IL2CPP enabled), Unity always fail in the last step, complaining it cannot find XCode.app/<path to build tool> in my "Download" folder, while I have XCode installed in "Applications" folder.
I have tried digging around try to find the place to config the path but to no avail, "git grep" my project for anything related to the Download folder does not yield any result. So I'm guessing the setting might have been saved in the Hub setting, Editor setting or some kind of "registry". If anyone know where to find this config, please let me know.

> - Unity: 2019.4.37f1
> - MacOS: 12.3.1
> - XCode: 13.4.1 (13F100)

Thank you

EDIT: Attaching editor log:

> Exception: /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.37f1/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/build/deploy/il2cppcore/il2cppcore.dll did not run properly!
> Failed running "/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.37f1/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/build/deploy/il2cppcore/il2cppcore.dll" --convert-to-cpp --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check --dotnetprofile="unityaot" --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="MacOSX" --architecture="x64" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="/Users/UserName/Projects/ProjectName/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Native/GameAssembly.dylib" --cachedirectory="/Users/UserName/Projects/ProjectName/Assets/../Library/il2cpp_cache" --profiler-report --map-file-parser="/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.37f1/Unity.app/Contents/Tools/MapFileParser/MapFileParser" --directory="/Users/UserName/Projects/ProjectName/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed" --generatedcppdir="/Users/UserName/Projects/ProjectName/Temp/StagingArea/Data/il2cppOutput"
> stdout:
> il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: System.InvalidOperationException: C++ code builder is unable to build C++ code. Please install Xcode at /Users/UserName/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ThrowIfCannotBuildInCurrentEnvironment()
> at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
> at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args, List`1 foundAssemblies)
> at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args, Boolean setInvariantCulture)
> at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)
> stderr:
> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: C++ code builder is unable to build C++ code. Please install Xcode at /Users/UserName/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ThrowIfCannotBuildInCurrentEnvironment()
> at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
> at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args, List`1 foundAssemblies)
> at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args, Boolean setInvariantCulture)
> at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)
> at Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/External/il2cpp/il2cpp/il2cppcore/Program.cs:line 24
> UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:126)
> UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunNetCoreProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:77)
> UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] arguments, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo, System.String workingDirectory) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:718)
> UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (UnityEditor.Il2Cpp.Il2CppBuildPipelineData data, System.String outputDirectory, System.String workingDirectory, System.Boolean platformSupportsManagedDebugging) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:701)
> UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:538)
> UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:273)
> DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.SetupStagingArea (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T] filesToNotOverwrite) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.cs:223)
> DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.cs:42)
> Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
> DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.cs:60)
> UnityEditor.OSXStandalone.OSXDesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/OSXPlayer/Extensions/Managed/OSXDesktopStandalonePostProcessor.cs:441)
> UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Modules/DefaultBuildPostprocessor.cs:29)
> UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:353)
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:197)

Comment: Please show the error in the editor log.

Answer (score 1):

Read this: https://www.unix.com/man-page/OSX/1/xcode-select/

I found that Unity uses xcode-select to determine the path of XCode.

Use the following command to change it.

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app
```

Or set the path for all users.

```
unset DEVELOPER_DIR
xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.
we are currently in a rush and ended up copy the XCode.app to the location mentioned by Unity to build for the time being.
When we finish the rush period I will give this solution a try and come back with result.
P/S: I also found we can select the XCode in build setting when switch platform to iOS, but not standalone, changing in other platform doesn't seem to affect standalone build either.